# Swift - Refactoring code. Closure and inout?

Tags: swift, refactoring

I have a class thats used to help manage the process of users sending emails with MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

The code is rather long, and I'm using it inside of almost all of my ViewControllers. And I figure I should be able to add it as an extension to UIVIewController. And so I'm currently trying to do that, but at a loss of how to do it correctly.

Working Code:

Struct:

```
struct Feedback {
    let recipients = [R.App.Contact.email] // [String]
    let subject: String
    let body: String
    let footer: String
}
```

Class:

```
final class FeedbackManager: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    private var feedback: Feedback
    private var completion: ((Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)?
    
    override init() {
        fatalError("Use FeedbackManager(feedback:)")
    }
    
    init?(feedback: Feedback) {
        print("init()")
        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
            return nil
        }
        self.feedback = feedback
    }
    
    func send(on viewController: UIViewController, completion:(@escaping(Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)) {
        print("send()")
        
        var appVersion = ""
        if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            appVersion = version
        }
        
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        self.completion = completion
        
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients(feedback.recipients)
        mailVC.setSubject(feedback.subject)
        mailVC.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)<br><br><br><br><br>\(feedback.footer)<br>Potfolio: (\(appVersion))<br>\(UIDevice.modelName) (\(UIDevice.current.systemVersion))</p>", isHTML: true)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            viewController.present(mailVC, animated:true)
        }
        
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        print("mailComposeController()")
        if let error = error {
            completion?(.failure(error))
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        } else {
            completion?(.success(result))
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager?

func sendEmail() {
        
        let feedback = Feedback(subject: "subject", body: "body", footer: "footer")
        
        if let manager = FeedbackManager(feedback: feedback) {
            self.feedbackManager = manager
            self.feedbackManager?.send(on: self) { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                case .success(_):
                    print("Success")
                }
                self?.feedbackManager = nil
            }
        } else { // Cant Send Email:
            let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please email " + R.App.Contact.email, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
            failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(failedMenu, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

My attempt to refractor:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    
    func refactoredEmail(on viewController: UIViewController, with feedback: Feedback, manager: inout FeedbackManager?) -> FeedbackManager? {
        
        guard let letManager = FeedbackManager(feedback: feedback) else {
            let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please email " + R.App.Contact.email, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
            failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                viewController.present(failedMenu, animated: true)
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        manager = letManager
        manager?.send(on: self) { [weak manager] result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            case .success(_):
                print("Success")
            }
            manager = nil
        }
        return letManager
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager?
    
    func sendEmail() {
        let feedback = Feedback(subject: "subject", body: "body", footer: "footer")
        refactoredEmail(on: self, with: feedback, manager: &feedbackManager)
    }
```

FeedbackManager Class is the same as above. --

---

As is, this *is* functional, but, `refactoredEmail` uses `feedbackManager` as an `inout` parameter. And `feedbackManager` is not returned to `nil` after completion.

I'm not entirely sure how bad (or not) it is to use `inout`. And I don't fully understand closures. However, my understanding is that the FeedbackManager Class must be a class because it subclasses `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`. And because of this, each ViewController needs it own reference to the class. Which is where `var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager?` comes in.

`feedbackManager` can then run the code inside the `FeedbackManager` Class. Which presents the `MFMailComposeViewController` on top of the ViewController that `feedbackManager` is in. But since now `refactoredEmail()` is an extension of UIViewController, my guess is the closure is capturing incorrectly?

In conclusion: **My goal** is to refractor the code so that implementing it in each view controller can hopefully be cut down in comparison with the first implementation code block.

Also, how bad is it to use `inout`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why manager is not nil after completion, but I can show you other way of implementation.

You could use associated objects:

```
protocol FeedbackShowable: class {
    func giveFeedback(with feedback: Feedback)
}

extension UIViewController: FeedbackShowable {
    private enum AssociatedObjectKeys {
        static var feedbackManager: String = "feedbackManager"
    }

    private var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKeys.feedbackManager) as? FeedbackManager
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                     &AssociatedObjectKeys.feedbackManager,
                                     newValue as FeedbackManager?,
                                     .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    func giveFeedback(with feedback: Feedback) {
        let feedbackManager = FeedbackManager(feedback: feedback)
        self.feedbackManager = feedbackManager
        feedbackManager.send(on: self) { [weak self] result in
            self?.feedbackManager = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My assumption is that because the closure doesn't implicitly say self.feedbackManager, that it's not getting returned correctly in the closure as a result. - I just also don't know how to get the correct ViewController to tap into in order to get it's `feedbackManager`.  Thank you for the answer as well! I didn't think about using protocols, so that's something I'll look into!