# Swift - Simplifying or refactoring an escaping closure? Can a closure be reusable?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm curious if there is a way to simplify / make a closure reusable? I asked a much more in depth question here: [Swift - Refactoring code. Closure and inout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783481/swift-refactoring-code-closure-and-inout/63784014#63784014) and its the same code in question.

What I'm trying to do is make this closure a single line:

```
self.feedbackManager?.send(on: self) { [weak self] result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    case .success(_):
        print("Success")
    }
    self?.feedbackManager = nil
}
```

`feedbackManager` is an instance of a class, which presents a `MFMailComposeViewController` on the `self.viewController`. The `result` is the `MFMailComposeResult`. Which is the `result` in the closure.

So that ideally, it can be called something like this?

```
self.feedbackManager?.send(on: self) { switchResultClosure }
```

---

**Edit: Result**

Implementation:

```
let feedback = Feedback(subject: "subject", body: "body", footer: "footer")
sendEmail(with: feedback, on: self)
```

Class:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

struct Feedback {
    let recipients = [R.App.Contact.email]
    let subject: String
    let body: String
    let footer: String
}


enum SendStatus: Int {
    case sent, cancelled, failed, notSupported, saved
}

protocol FeedbackProtocol {
    func sendEmail(with feedback: Feedback, on viewController: UIViewController)
}

extension FeedbackProtocol {
    func sendEmail(with feedback: Feedback, on viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("protocol FeedbackController: sendEmail()")
        ShareController.shared.sendMailToRecipients(with: feedback, on: viewController) { (SendStatus) in
            print("SendStatus: ", SendStatus)
        }
    }
}

final class ShareController: NSObject {
    
    static var shared = ShareController()
    var completionBlock: ((SendStatus) -> Void)?
    
    private override init() { }
    
}

extension ShareController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func sendMailToRecipients(with feedback: Feedback, on viewController: UIViewController, block: @escaping (SendStatus) -> Void) {
        print("sendMailToRecipients()")
        
        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
            block(.notSupported)
            return
        }
        
        var appVersion = ""
        if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            appVersion = version
        }
        
        completionBlock = block
        let mailController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailController.setToRecipients(feedback.recipients)
        mailController.setSubject(feedback.subject)
        mailController.setMessageBody((feedback.body), isHTML: true)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            viewController.present(mailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        print("mailComposeController(): ShareVC")
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        switch result {
        case .sent: completionBlock?(.sent)
        case .cancelled: completionBlock?(.cancelled)
        case .failed: completionBlock?(.failed)
        case .saved: completionBlock?(.saved)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just extract the switch statement into a function and call that function? Or do you want to do that, but don't know how?

Comment: I want to do that but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do by creating function with same parameter as your closure.
Call below function. instead of writing closure in send just type **switchResultClosure** with out brackets. Syntax might not be accurate.

```
func switchResultClosure(result: ResultDataType) {
    // switch code
    switch result {
    case let .failure(error):
        print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    case .success:
        print("Success")
    }
    self?.feedbackManager = nil
}

feedbackManager?.send(on: self, switchResultClosure)
```

Comment: Thank you! That gave me something to work with! If you don't mind, I edited in the code I'm now using. It's working, but I was curious if anything on it looks suspicious?

Comment: Don't you think it is too much code for simple mail feature?
What you can do is create shared Instance class. Create sendEmail method to send email and get mail sent status in same method.

Comment: Check out this simple class I've created.
https://ibb.co/61Yr4hs

Comment: I do think it's a lot of code. But it's less code than it previously was! - I've been messing with this code for about a month now. And while it's still a work and progress, I must say that I have learned a lot from it. - Especially with closures, thanks to your help. - I'm just now looking at the class you made, so I will be back in a  bit once I've gotten the chance to give it a try!

Comment: Thank you! I think I've got it working! I re-edited the initial post with the updated code. It's a mix of what I had, and what you suggested!